# Subir imagen con Angular

Tags: angular, imagen

tengo un problema que no puedo resolver. y es como enviar la info de por ejemplo un producto con imagen al servidor desde angular.
Tengo un servidor hecho en Node
La funcion que hice para almacenar produtos es la siguiente.

```
async function addProduct (req,res) {
    try{
        const { 
            name,
            size,
            unitaryPrice,
            description,
        } = req.body

        const product = Product({
            name,
            size,
            unitaryPrice,
            description,
        })

        if(req.file){

            const {filename} = req.file
            const port = config.get('configDB.HOST')
            product.imgUrl = `${port}/public/${filename}`
        }

        const productStored = await  product.save()
        res.status(201).send({productStored})

    }catch (e){
        res.status(500).send({message: e.message})
    }
}
```

Uso Multer para almacenar la imagen

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './storage/imgs')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
  })
  
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

  module.exports = upload
```

y luego llamo las dos funciones desde la ruta

```
api.post('/', upload.single('image') , addProduct)
```

Mi pregunta es, como hago para enviar esa informacion al servidor desde un front hecho en Angular.

Comment: Cambiaste la imagen a base64??

Comment: Hola Alfa, nono, no eh cambiado la imagen, mi problema es que no se como hacer la parte del front para poder subir la información junto con la imagen

Answer (score 0):

```
> Para  enviar solo la imagen desde el Front
```

[enviar imagen stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472530/image-upload-issue-using-angular-node-express-multer)

```
    // html
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" (ngSubmit)="uploadImage()">
   <input type="file" name="image" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
   <button>Save Image</button>
</form>
 //ts
formData = new FormData();

  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.uploadedImage = event.target.files[0]
}

uploadImage() {
    if (this.uploadedImage) {
      this.formData.append('image', this.uploadedImage, this.uploadedImage.name)
      console.log(this.formData.getAll('image')) //confirms file is being uploaded properly
      this.httpService.upload('uploadImage/', this.formData).subscribe((message: any) => {
        console.log(message)
      });
}

//httpService
  upload(url, file) {
    console.log("uploading file")
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + url, file);
  }
```

......................................

> Ejemplo de como multer es usado en formulario HTML

```
<form action="/stats" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of speakers" name="nspeakers">
    <input type="submit" value="Get me the stats!" class="btn btn-default">            
  </div>
</form>
```

[ejemplo node+multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)